# Pre-compiled ASP.NET MVC views get slow after a while in Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, precompiled-views

I have been using pre-compiled views in my product publish / deploy process. We have experienced a much faster start and overall application performance. BUT, after a while (hours), we start to get slow pages again. The immediate solution for this is to restart our Azure Web App.

I would like to understand the root cause for this, so we can avoid restarting the Azure Web App when it happens.

I'm using C#, ASP.NET MVC v4.8, Azure App Service.

Even with the pre-compiled views, it seems to be still compiling the views during page loads. Following a trace of Azure Profiler.

[image]

Comment: What did you try? Did you investigate a dump? Where are the resources going?

Comment: I did a profiler on Azure Diagostic Tools, and found that the .cshtml.Execute are the offenders regarding loading performance. I will add the print screen in the original question.

Comment: Any update to this? I'm seeing the same issue